# How to ignore a rule if its dependency does not exist?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with two rules. One which converts a database file into a SQL file and one which does the opposite.

```
all:

data.sql: data.sqlite3
    sqlite3 $< .dump > $@

data.sqlite3: data.sql
    sqlite3 $@ < $<
```

This works, but I get warnings about circular dependencies.

```
$ rm data.sql
$ make data.sql
make: Circular data.sqlite3 <- data.sql dependency dropped.
sqlite3 data.sqlite3 .dump > data.sql

$ rm data.sqlite3 
$ make data.sqlite3
make: Circular data.sql <- data.sqlite3 dependency dropped.
sqlite3 data.sqlite3 < data.sql
```

Is it possible to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own solution I gather it's never the case that
an `.sql` and an `.sqlite3` exist at the same time. In that
case you can be more concise by making each missing `.sql`
or `.sqlite3` as a side-effect of pretending to make a proxy target but
never actually doing it. Here's an illustration:

```
# These are the missing `.sql` files for which a `.sqlite3` exists...
sql_missing = $(filter-out \
    $(wildcard *.sql),$(addsuffix .sql,$(basename $(wildcard *.sqlite3))))
# These are the missing `.sqlite3` files for which an `.sql` exists...
sqlite3_missing = $(filter-out \
    $(wildcard *sqlite3),$(addsuffix .sqlite3,$(basename $(wildcard *.sql))))
# There are the proxy targets...
targs = $(addsuffix _missing,$(sql_missing) $(sqlite3_missing))

.PHONY: all

all: $(targs)

%.sql_missing: %.sqlite3
    @echo "$< => $(basename $@).sql"
    @touch $(basename $@).sql

%.sqlite3_missing: %.sql
    @echo "$< => $(basename $@).sqlite3"
    @touch $(basename $@).sqlite3
```

This caters for a population of either filetype or both in the directory,
as long as you only want to remake the *missing* file of each incomplete pair.

In use:

```
$ ls
Makefile
$ touch f1.sql
$ touch f2.sqlite3
$ make
f2.sqlite3 => f2.sql
f1.sql => f1.sqlite3
$ ls
f1.sql  f1.sqlite3  f2.sql  f2.sqlite3  Makefile
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Comment: Tricky. Make does not bother that the target gets never done by the rule it should do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. A bit verbose but it seems to work.

```
DBFILE := data.sqlite3
SQLFILE := data.sql

ifeq ("$(wildcard $(SQLFILE))","")
MISSING := $(SQLFILE)
endif

ifeq ("$(wildcard $(DBFILE))","")
MISSING := $(DBFILE)
endif

all: $(MISSING)

ifeq ("$(wildcard $(SQLFILE))","")
$(SQLFILE): $(DBFILE)
    sqlite3 $< .dump > $@
endif

ifeq ("$(wildcard $(DBFILE))","")
$(DBFILE): $(SQLFILE)
    sqlite3 $@ < $<
endif
```